# How can I get the different elements for two List with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I hope to get the different elements in two list, how can I do it with Kotlin?

Such as , the different elements is 9 and 10 in Code A.

**Code A**

```
val mutableList1 = mutableListOf(1,2,7,8)        
val mutableList2 = mutableListOf(1,2,7,8,9,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[filterNot](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/filter-not.html)**:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val mutableList1 = mutableListOf(1, 2, 7, 8)
    val mutableList2 = mutableListOf(1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    val differentElements = mutableList2.filterNot { mutableList1.contains(it) }
    println(differentElements)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[9, 10]
```